# Banner Management

Tags: 7

Anyone knows is there any plugin/Module which can provide banner/slider management with basic functionality plus play & pause functionality on the banner

Please Guys what to do? Suggestions welcome

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/node/418616

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve above using [Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module...

Project page says

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not
>   just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is
>   heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View
>   you create.

- Create a content type called Slideshow Banner
- Add Image Field
- Create view which lists above content and use display type Slideshow

Comment: is it with play & pause functionality??

Comment: Yes.. It has above controls..

Comment: let me check then, hopefully i get the controls what i want :)

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/187716

Comment: i know that buddy.. first let me check ;)